# sha256sum of image on dvd doesn't match to original ISO

Tags: iso, dvd, dd, checksums

I tried to check sha256sum of ISO after it was burn on DVD I used this command and got result that differs from original ISO's check:

```
dd if=/dev/sr0 | sha256sum
```

Does it mean that it was written with errors ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/830426/272880 (You need the *size*).